# Hierarchy view not being respected - UI Route (Ionic)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic app and I have implemented an on-boarding screen with 3 slides, some text, and `<a href="...">` tag to go directly to the start screen.

Now I have noticed that when I hit the `<a href="...">` tag I am redirected to the correct view but the nav bar on top has a back button where there should be a hamburger menu icon.

Not sure if I am implementing the routing system right. What is the right why to use routing and respect the hierarchical view?

[image]
[image]

Html code (on-boarding):

```
<ion-view view-title="WNRS" hide-nav-bar="true">
  <ion-content scroll="false" has-header="true" class="has-header">
      <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideChanged(index)">
          <ion-slide>
            <h4  class="padding">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque semper, sapien ac hendrerit porttitor, ipsum ante ultrices ipsum, eu congue arcu libero id enim.</h4>
            <br><br>
            <a ui-sref="app.base1"><h2>Play</h2></a>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
            <h4 class="padding">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque semper, sapien ac hendrerit porttitor, ipsum ante ultrices ipsum, eu congue arcu libero id enim.</h4>
            <br><br>
            <a ui-sref="app.base1"><h2>Play</h2></a>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
             <h4 class="padding">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque semper, sapien ac hendrerit porttitor, ipsum ante ultrices ipsum, eu congue arcu libero id enim.</h4>
             <br><br>
             <a ui-sref="app.base1"><h2>Play</h2></a>
          </ion-slide>
      </ion-slide-box>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Part of the app.js code (routing part):

```
// Routes
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'components/sidebar_menu/menu.html'
  })

  .state('app.walkthrough', {
    url: '/walkthrough',
    views: {
       'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'views/walkthrough/walkthrough.html',
          controller: 'WalkthroughCtrl' 
        }  
      }
  })

  .state('app.base1', {
    url: '/base1',
    views: {
       'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'views/base1/base1.html',
          controller: 'Base1Ctrl'
        }  
      }
  })

  .state('app.base2', {
    url: '/base2',
    views: {
       'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'views/base2/base2.html',
          controller: 'Base2Ctrl'
        }  
      }
  })

  .state('app.base3', {
    url: '/base3',
    views: {
       'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'views/base3/base3.html',
          controller: 'Base3Ctrl'
        }  
      }
  })

  .state('app.add_question', {
    url: '/add_question',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'views/add_question/add_question.html',
        controller: 'AddQuestionCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/walkthrough');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two Choices: 1. Make the walkthrough page the parent, and base1, base2, base3 should be child page. But even in this way, if you switch from base1 to base2, you will still see the "back" button on base2 page.

Or you can simply customize the ion-nav-bar in base1, base2, base3 like this:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
      <button class="button your-hambuger" menu-toggle="left">
      </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-nav-title>
        Base1
    </ion-nav-title>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-content>
    Some content  
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Update: if you want to disable back button on base1 for example, you can add below code to your base1 controller:

```
.controller('Base1Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    //add below code to disable back button
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event, viewData) {
        viewData.enableBack = false; 
    });
}])
```

Update2: if you want to do some custimization on the nav bar. I think choice 2 is the only option. First go to your menu.html and remove ion-nav-bar part. Copy this part to the pages where you want to show ion-nav-bar with a hamburger icon.  For those pages you want to show back button, you can add ion-header-bar code to that page:

```
<ion-view view-title="Base2">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable" id="nav-bar">
    <button ng-click="goState()" class="button back-button buttons button-clear header-item">
      <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-back"></i> 
      <span class="back-text"><span class="default-title">Base1</span></span>
    </button>
    <div class="title title-center header-item">Base2</div>
    <button ng-click="goState2()" class="button back-button buttons button-clear header-item">      
      <span class="back-text"><span class="default-title">Base3</span></span>
      <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i> 
    </button>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
     Base2 content
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[image]
You can add the goState() function in base2 controller or just give an ui-sref to that button

Comment: i just wanted to test option 2 out of curiosity. and then i don' see a nav bar only the title. More interested in option 1. So i should delete the app route which is now the parent correct?

Comment: You can see the title, that means there is a bar, maybe the background is white...  For 1st choice, I still don't think you need to mess up the state. You can try to disable the back button before entering base123 page

Comment: Updated answer showing how to disable back button when switching state

Comment: mmm, i dont really want to disable back button because i need it i just want it to say back instead of base 1, base 2 or base 3. see this link -> https://gyazo.com/d721f22ae71e1a81727b01b133d3b681 This is when i am in view base 2 normally it should say back but instead is says base 1

Comment: In my view base 1 there is an ion-slide-box consisting of 12 slides on the last slide a button shows that enables the user to go to view 2 (base 2). in my controller of base 1, i have this bit of code for linking to view 2: $scope.goToBase2 = function () {
        $rootScope.setGameBase(2);
        $rootScope.setGameLevel(0);
        $state.go('app.base2');
    };

Comment: So you want back button and hamburger icon on base2 at the same time?

Comment: mmmm, your update to explanation is not really working for me. if i implement the nav bar in the pages where i want a back button then it will do that but the title will not show.

Comment: Just update the answer with full customized header bar example

Comment: The ion-nav-bar in menu.html acts like a global header bar. If you want different nav-bar in different pages, you need to delete this global bar and create specific ones.